# Pandas - Flag when one item is different

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
date,         item,         value
2015-01-20    abc            1
2015-01-20    xyz           -1
2015-01-20    fgh            1
2015-01-20    iop           -1
2015-01-21    abc            1
2015-01-21    xyz            1
2015-01-21    fgh           -1
2015-01-21    iop            1
```

I need to go through each day and flag an item if it is the only item for that day which has a different value to the rest. They could have any values, the point is to identify when there is only one item that differs from the rest for each day.

For example on 2015-01-20 two items have value 1 and two items have value -1, therefore there is nothing to flag. However on 2015-01-21, only one item has value -1 while the rest have value 1 therefore I need to flag item 'fgh'.

The output of the above would therefore be:

```
date,         item,         value    flag
2015-01-20    abc            1
2015-01-20    xyz           -1
2015-01-20    fgh            1
2015-01-20    iop           -1
2015-01-21    abc            1
2015-01-21    xyz            1
2015-01-21    fgh           -1       True
2015-01-21    iop            1
```

Im not aware of anything built into pandas to do this? If not, is there a reasonably elegant way to accomplish this.

**Edit**

To simplify, I would be able to ensure that the value column is either positive or negative meaning that I would simply need to identify when one value is positive while the rest are negative, or vice-versa.

Comment: I would have suggested `df['flag'] = df.groupby('date')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts() == 1)` but this is not doing what I expect and there looks like there is a bug here

Comment: hmmm, looks like im really going to have to think outside of the box to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

First use a `groupby` to get the aggregate function that you want, in this case a flag against each date and value:

```
singleton_values = (df.groupby(['date,','value'])['item,'].count()==1)
singleton_values = singleton_values.reset_index()
singleton_values.rename(columns = {'item,':'flag'}, inplace= True)        
singleton_values

        date,  value   flag
0  2015-01-20     -1  False
1  2015-01-20      1  False
2  2015-01-21     -1   True
3  2015-01-21      1  False
```

Then merge back to the original dataframe to have your aggregates displayed against each row:

```
df = pd.merge(df,singleton_values)
df

        date, item,  value   flag
0  2015-01-20   abc      1  False
1  2015-01-20   fgh      1  False
2  2015-01-20   xyz     -1  False
3  2015-01-20   iop     -1  False
4  2015-01-21   abc      1  False
5  2015-01-21   xyz      1  False
6  2015-01-21   iop      1  False
7  2015-01-21   fgh     -1   True
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it should work. Unfortunately im getting an issue when trying to do the rename. singleton_values is of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> therefore I cannot use .rename. Rename is only valid for dataframes, not series. The true/false column does not have a column name, so how would I rename it and then merge it back into the original dataframe? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot a line (reset_index), the code should work for you now.